# Quotient of ring of algebraic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am facing the following problem in my commutative algebra course:

> Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of the ring of algebraic integers $\overline{\mathbf{Z}}$. Prove that $\overline {\mathbf{Z}}/\mathfrak m$ is isomorphic to an algebraic closure of a finite field.

We have $\mathfrak{m}\cap \mathbf{Z}=(p)$ for some prime $p$, so $L:= {\mathbf{Z}}/\mathfrak m$ is a field of characteristic $p$, so a field extension of $\mathbf{F}_p$. We want to prove it is algebraically closed, since algebraic closures of a same field are isomorphic.

However, I don't see how I would use the fact that $\overline{\mathbf{Z}}$ is the ring of algebraic integers. Any help is appreciated, however I am looking for a **hint**.

EDIT. I think this works:

Take a non-constant polynomial $f$ in $L[X]$. Let $\tilde{f}=X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1X+a_0\in \overline{\mathbf{Z}}[X]$ be a lift of $f$. As $\overline{\mathbf{Z}}$ is subset of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ and the latter is algebraically closed, $\tilde{f}$ has a zero $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbf{Q}}$. This element $\alpha$ is integral over $\mathbf{Z}[a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}]$, which is integral over $\mathbf{Z}$ (since each $a_i\in \overline{\mathbf{Z}}$), hence $\alpha$ is integral over $\mathbf{Z}$. We conclude that $\alpha$ is an element of $\overline{\mathbf{Z}}$. The image of $\alpha$ in $L$ is a zero of $f$, proving that $L$ is algebraically closed. Since $L$ has characteristic $p$, by unicity of algebraic closures, we know that  $L:=\mathbf{Z}/\mathfrak{m}\cong \overline{\mathbf{F}_p}$.

Comment: Didn't think completely about it but how about: Take a non-constant polynomial in $L$ and lift it to $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$?